# Finally clause executing before end of try

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have some code that I run when loading a Vue 3 page. It looks like this:

```
async function initializeAllData() {
  // Handles API call
  await httpService.getData();
}

async function getData() {
  try {
    await initializeAllData();
    loadError.value = false;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Something went wrong while initializing connections: ${e}`);
    loadError.value = true;
  } finally {
    // This part always executes immediately, instead of after the `try` clause
    isPageReady.value = true;
  }
}

await getData();
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the `finally` clause to execute *after* the `try` clause is done (e.g. after the data has been fetched). I've done a deep dive on here and have tried all kinds of combinations of promises with `.then()` and `Promise.all()` clauses, but to no avail.

I need the `isPageReady.value` to be set to `true` only when the data has been fetched, as this is controlling the 'loading' screen logic on the page. I have no idea why, but the `finally` clause always executes immediately, well before the request has been completed.

Comment: Looks like a code smell if your *asynchronous function* has to *mutate global variables*. Why not just return a promise that resolves to the values for those global variables?

Comment: `await` means that you will be initiating an asynchronous operation and that the rest of the code should proceed (which is why the `finally` branch runs). You need to set up a callback for when the async operation returns.

Comment: @Scott, that would be true without `await`, but `await` will make the function return and suspends its further execution until the promise that is awaited has resolved. The finally block cannot execute before that promise settles, so I guess it resolves sooner than the OP thought it did.

Comment: The `await` operator is used to wait for a Promise and get its fulfillment value. What Scott is describing is more akin to an `async` function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: My guess is there is something else that is the problem if that is what you are seeing.

Comment: If the `finally` clause is executing before everything inside of `initializeAllData()` is done, then the problem is inside of `initializeAllData()`.  `await` ONLY works when you are awaiting a promise that resolves/rejects when the underlying operation is done.  If `initializeData()` does not return a promise or if that promise resolves before all of its work is done, then there is absolutely nothing you can do from outside that function using `await` to know when it's done.  You have to fix `initializeData()` so it returns a promise that resolves/rejects only when the work is done.

Comment: And, since `initializeData()` seems to just be calling `httpService.getData();`, then perhaps the problem is in that code where it needs to be returning a promise that only resolves/rejects when its work is done.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code:

```
async function initializeAllData() {
    // Handles API call
    console.log("this should be step 1");
}

async function getData() {
    try {
        await initializeAllData();
        console.log("this should be step 2");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`this shouldn't appear unless an error is present`);
    } finally {
        console.log("this should be step 3");
    }
}

await getData();
```

I get the response:

```
"this should be step 1"
"this should be step 2"
"this should be step 3"
```

So, I don't think that there's anything wrong with your sequence control.

More than likely, something is happening in `httpService.getData()` that needs to be looked at. You should ensure that this method is also asynchronous. Otherwise, it will immediately return an unfulfilled Promise, which sounds quite similar to what you're describing with your issue.

```
const httpService = {
    getService: async function (url) {
        const http = await fetch(url);
        const response = await http.text();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Josh! I will look into the server-side code to try and deal with this. This is really helpful and might help explain why I'm getting nowhere with this. I appreciate it!

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. Hope it works!!